# Who was the relief navigator in Star Trek: The Motion Picture?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, star-trek-the-motion-picture

After Ilia is taken by V'ger, another woman takes the navigator station. Who was this character?

Comment: Can you provide a photo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Chief DiFalco](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/DiFalco)**

[image]

From [her official Star Trek page](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/difalco):

> Starfleet officer aboard the U.S.S. Enterprise under the command of Willard Decker and later James T. Kirk. She was serving as relief navigator when the Enterprise intercepted the V'Ger machine lifeform. When Ilia was abducted by V'Ger, DiFalco replaced her in her post on the bridge.

She was played by [Marcy Lafferty](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Marcy_Lafferty), William Shatner's second wife, married to him from 1973 to 1996.

Comment: @Gallifeyan  I included your link in my answer, thank you.

Comment: @Gallifeyan Maybe our edits crossed each others, I didn't see how your edit improved my answer.  As you were editing, I also was adding the character's name and link.

Comment: @Gallifeyan  be my guest thank you for the improvements

Comment: Is my edit alright? Feel free to edit or roll back.

Comment: @Gallifeyan thank you